# How Augmented reality developers manage fundings

Tags: augmented-reality, development-environment, arkit, finance

I am currently making a research on Augmented reality for my seminar paper and part of it needs to cover fundings, I need to know how an AR developer makes money or generally how he/she finances the whole development.

Comment: This is your "research"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about research & funding instead of directly about programming & coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main ways we’ve seen:

AR contract services: Design agencies usually create custom augmented reality experiences for brands and for marketing purposes. Such contracts will usually work like any app developers working for larger brands. Coca-colas various AR experiences come to mind

App market: With the advent of ARkit and ARCore, there is now a slew of apps that have hit the market with active participation from developers. These make money exactly how other apps do, fees to buy the app, advertisements that run within the app or subscriptions.

Hope this helps!